# How to convert a string to corresponding day,month and date

Tags: java, android, string

Say for eg: I have

```
    String a= "may 22-may 28  Free"
```

which comes from response.
from service how to change that to like this?

```
    Tue,5.22- thur,5.28
```

**Note:** two space been given at last ie after date and then a text as free, so neglecting that and considering only date from response,how to do? any idea?

```
    DateFormatter formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy:HH:mm:SS");
    convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(a);
```

but this i couldn't achieve because i couldn't split and properly display based on the 
expected output

as like this Tue,5.22- thur,5.28.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ans second number is supposed to be same month?

Comment: no @m0skit0 suppose from service if it comes as jul 31- aug 2, it varies

Comment: And what is the year? Current one? Also for a inter-year date interval, how to know the starting year? Is it previous one or current one (for example dec 31-jan 2)?

Comment: current year. @m0skit0

Comment: @user3848333 Edit your question when adding clarification, rather post as comments. Notice the `edit` link above left, beneath the tags on your question.

Answer (score 0):

The is no in-built Parser available for the String you have and the return type you want. You can check all the available Date and Time patterns supported here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

You shall have to write your own parser.

You can try to split the String with '-' first and ' ' (space further). And then I am sure you can easily get your format.

Simple code would be :

> String a= "may 22-may 28 Free" ;  String[] array = new String[2];
>   array =  a.split('-');
>
> // You will hv the array set to {'may 22','may 28 Free'} - Let's take
>   first array value, i.e. array[0]
>
> String date[] = new String[2]; date = array[0].split('');
>
> // You will have date array set to {'may', '22'}

You can create a switch-case to return proper month number for Month('may') strings, use the date ('22')  as it is.

For getting the Day of the week - use below code : (Make Sure you have Year too)

> Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.setTime(yourDate); 
>   int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

This is the simplest of the code I can suggest. You can surely improvise it further. Also whenever you get an array with more than 2 attributes (as per given example) the last string is 'Free' and you can stop your execution there.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
    final String a = "dec 22-may 28";
    final int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final SimpleDateFormat stringToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
    final SimpleDateFormat dateToString = new SimpleDateFormat("EE,M.dd");
    final String[] dates = a.split("-");

    // First
    Date convertedDate = stringToDate.parse(dates[0]);
    final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(convertedDate);
    c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentYear);
    System.out.println(c1.getTime());
    System.out.println(dateToString.format(c1.getTime()));

    // Second
    convertedDate = stringToDate.parse(dates[1]);
    final Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(convertedDate);
    c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentYear);
    if (c2.before(c1)) {
        c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentYear + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(c2.getTime());
    System.out.println(dateToString.format(c2.getTime()));
```

Keep in mind that I used *dec-may* because it's worst case I can think of. Also note I take first date as current year, second date might be next year (like in this case).

Answer (score -1):

You can try it using below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a= "may 22-may 28"  ;
    String[]arr = a.split("-");
    String date1 = arr[0];
    String date2 = arr[1];

    String result = getFormattedDate(date1) +"- " + getFormattedDate(date2);
    System.out.println(result); 
    //Output is Fri,5.22- Thu,5.28

}

public static String getFormattedDate(String inputDate){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EE,M.dd");
    String result = "";
    Date d1 = null;
    try {
        d1 = sdf.parse(inputDate);
        result = sdf2.format(d1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```